# Does RegExp behave differently on different environments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I've created a Restful API in node that checks for words within a sentence.  The code works while running locally.  Running from production results in unexpected results.

The production environment consists of Windows Server 2016 w/ IIS 10 and IISNode.

```
function checkForWords(text) {
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (new RegExp("\\b" + word[i] + "\\b", "i").test(text)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

On the local environment searching the word 'hell' in the text 'hello world' returns 'false' which is the correct behaviour.

On the production environment searching the word 'hell' in the text 'hello world' returns 'true'.

Comment: Do you use webpack or something of similar kind? Transpiling your code might raise this issue albeit very unlikely.

Comment: Different environments can leverage different regex flavors... and there are [a lot of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines). You haven't provided information about your local environment, but if there is a discrepancy between the results I'd assume your local environment doesn't match the production environment.

Comment: Do any of the `words` contain metacharacters like `[]\.` etc?

Comment: are both environments running the same version of node? store the result of the constructor and log it, is the generated expression the same on both your local and production environments?